# Whats the best way to pass objects between storyboard views?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Say I have a storyboard app with 2 views and viewcontrollers linked up with a navigation controller, what would be the best way to pass an object from the first viewcontroller to the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `PrepareForSegue` on the first controller.

```
public class ViewControllerA : UICollectionViewController
{
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender) 
    {
        var destination = (ViewControllerB)segue.DestinationViewController;
        destination.SomeProperty = 2;
        destination.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

You will probably need to check the name of `segue` before doing the cast, if you have several different segues originating from A.